# Altering TeXStudio autocompletion to use a (tab) trigger

Tags: texstudio

I have started using Macros for faster typesetting recently in TeXStudio.

I use triggers like "eqn" for eqnarray, "list" for creating lists. The problem is that as soon as I write list, it is replaced by the code. This restricts me from using list as a word in my document.

I was wondering if I can add TAB at the end of the trigger so that it inserts the code only when I press tab after the trigger text.

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray`, or to put it in a more standards conforming way: [Avoid eqnarray!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: Another idea, apart from using TAB, you might use upper case keywords, like `LIST` instead.

Comment: Welcome! I've removed the 'macros' tag because it means something different and quite specific here, which has nothing to do with your question.